# GPG - Change passphrase non interactively

Tags: encryption, keychain, gnupg

Most other GPG commands allow you to use --batch mode, but it doesn't appear to be the case when trying to edit a passphrase.

You have to run `gpg --edit-key user`

Which opens up an interactive GPG prompt.

This isn't going to work in my case as I need the ability to change the passphrase without the command line interaction.

The closest thing I've found is

`gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --status-fd 2 --command-fd 0 --edit-key`

But this just gives me an invalid command after I enter the existing passphrase.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you can't. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278841/centos-change-the-password-of-gpg-file-by-bash-script/278853#278853, for example.

Comment: You cannot do it non-interactively. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered this problem while writing a key-gen script and came up with a solution!

A few things to note:

1. Lots of folks point towards `--batch` because `--passphrase*` requires it. In this case we'll be working with `STDIN` (as specified by `--command-fd 0`) and thus want to pass raw input rather than messing with the GnuPG functions.
2. While `--status-fd 2` is useful for debugging, it isn't necessary. That said, including it lead me to the insight that `--change-passphrase` is requesting two, and only two, entries.
3. Set `--pinentry-mode loopback` to avoid having a prompt asking for your passphrase.

The solution is to pipe (or redirect) both the original and new passphrases to `STDIN` where GnuPG can processes them. While my initial code used `(echo ..;echo ..)|gpg ..` it is better to use a [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).

```
# Using GnuPG to change PGP key passphrase non-interactively
gpg --command-fd 0 --pinentry-mode loopback \
    --change-passphrase ${KEYID} <<END
${OLD_PASS}
${NEW_PASS}
END
```

Just set up the variables and that should work. Enjoy!